# HTML5 Validation missing in VS2010 service pack 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, validation, html, intellisense

I recently installed the service pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010. The problem is, when I select the "HTML5" value for the validation target, I start getting validation warnings for almost all elements in the HTML document, and intellisense stops working (it's like the .XSD for HTML5 is missing). When I select "XHTML5" as validation target, intellisense works and all the validation warnings dissappear.

I got no error messages when installing the service pack, so I have no clues on what's happening. One thing to note, before installing the service pack 1, I was using this extension to provide HTML5 support:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d/

I uninstalled it after installing the service pack. Perhaps has something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing and it looks like the html5 extension removes the xsd (not verified, but my html_5.xsd was missing).

I downloaded the html5 extension again and extracted the contents of the msi: (msiexec /a c:\html5setup.msi /qb TARGETDIR=c:\html5Extract) and then navigated through the extracted folder structure until I found the html_5.xsd.

I then copied it into my VS2010 install location: 
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html)

Re-opened VS and all looks to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I copied in the html_5.xsd file, but that was trying to import i18languages.xsd and svg.xsd, and I didn't have **svg.xsd**. Luckily, I had a copy on another computer, but I imagine you could get it in the same way as [justinlabenne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5405745/6910) did.